# Laravel Salesforce Api using Omniphx/Forrest LaravelSession Error Exception

Tags: php, laravel, session, salesforce

Setup of Laravel 5.3 with Salesforce API Server flow.

Finding an issue installing Forrest, site runs on https

> ErrorException in LaravelSession.php line 15: Argument 2 passed to
>   Omniphx\Forrest\Providers\Laravel\LaravelSession::__construct() must
>   be     an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session, instance
>   of Illuminate\Session\Store given, called in
>   vendor/omniphx/forrest/src/Omniphx/Forrest/Providers/Laravel/ForrestServiceProvider.php
>   on line 36 and defined'

Version 2.4
Routes defined with Web middleware.
Config setup in forrest.php
Session driver 'file'

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is an issue with the repo.

https://github.com/omniphx/forrest/issues/161

Choose version 2.4.2 and fixes issue